# Пунктуация в заголовке

Tags: пунктуация, многоточие

Для описания коротких исторических фактов в туристическом путеводителе используется заголовок: "А вы знали, что?" и далее идёт соответствующий исторический факт. Вопрос: правильна ли пунктуация в этом случае? Не правильнее ли будет: "А вы знали, что..?", либо "А вы знали, что?..", либо правильнее упростить до "А вы знали?".
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вообще ограничился многоточием: *А вы знали, что...*

Варианты *А вы знали, что?* (бессмысленный вопрос) и *А вы знали, что..?* (некорректное сочетание знаков) неверны,  вариант с *?..* (подчеркивается, что мысль продолжается; есть связь с последующим текстом) или без *что* (вполне нормальный вопрос) выглядят лучше.

UPD: В книге известного лингвиста Натальи Александровны Еськовой "Популярная и занимательная филология" встречается заголовок: "Знаете ли вы, что**...?**". Это довольно необычное сочетание знаков (*сочетание* ли это вообще?), однако, как видно, оно встречается.

Answer (score 0):

**"А знаете ли вы, что некоторые виды птиц ставят какие-то абсолютно невероятные рекорды по беспосадочным полетам".**

Возможно, только вот где знак вопроса в конце предложения? Его почему-то очень часто пропускают (хотя не всегда). Вот и в заголовке "А знаете ли вы, что..." вопросительный знак может отсутствовать.

Что касается самого заголовка, то его действительно пишут как кому вздумается (и выбрать самую правильную запись довольно затруднительно), поэтому более логичным кажется другой вариант, более простой и понятный: **А вы это знаете?**

Чем он хуже? Или уж остановиться на варианте без многоточия: **"А знаете ли вы?"**